# Trouble Filtering Firestore Data by Date Range Using Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm encountering issues while trying to filter Firestore data within a specific date range using Cloud Functions. Here's a brief overview of the problem:

**Problem:**

**Objective:** To retrieve Firestore data for a specified date range.

**Issue:** Despite attempts to filter data for a particular date range, the query seems to include incorrect data or exclude relevant entries.

**Details:** I'm using a Cloud Function where I convert input start and end dates to UTC and compare them against Firestore timestamps. However, the filtering doesn't seem to work accurately as expected.

**What I've Tried:**

Converting input dates to UTC and adjusting them to the start and end of the day for accurate comparison.
Converting Firestore timestamps to UTC before comparison.
Sample Code (Summary):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.getExpenses = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth.uid) {
    return { error: 'Unauthorized' };
  }

  const startDate = new Date(data.startDate);
  const endDate = new Date(data.endDate);

  // Convert start and end dates to UTC
  const startUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0));
  const endUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate(), 23, 59, 59, 999));

  const shopId = data.shopId;

  try {
    const expensesSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('expensesRegister')
      .where('shopId', '==', shopId)
      .get();

    const expenseData = [];

    for (const doc of expensesSnapshot.docs) {
      const expenseName = doc.data().expenseName;
      const businessExpensesRef = doc.ref.collection('business_expenses');

      const businessExpensesSnapshot = await businessExpensesRef.get();
      let totalAmount = 0;

      businessExpensesSnapshot.forEach(expenseDoc => {
        const expenseDate = expenseDoc.data().date.toDate();

        // Convert Firestore timestamp to UTC for comparison
        const expenseDateUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(expenseDate.getFullYear(), expenseDate.getMonth(), expenseDate.getDate(), expenseDate.getHours(), expenseDate.getMinutes(), expenseDate.getSeconds(), expenseDate.getMilliseconds()));

        // Adjust time to start and end of the days for comparison
        expenseDateUTC.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (expenseDateUTC >= startUTC && expenseDateUTC <= endUTC) {
          totalAmount += expenseDoc.data().amount;
        }
      });

      expenseData.push({
        expenseName,
        totalAmount
      });
    }

    return { expenseData };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: error.message };
  }
});
```

Sample Query Payload:

```
{
  "startDate": "2023-11-18T00:00:00Z",
  "endDate": "2023-11-20T23:59:59.999Z",
  "shopId": "10973697"
}
```

**Expected Outcome:**
My expectation is to precisely retrieve Firestore data strictly within the specified date range (e.g., from 18th Nov to 20th Nov) without incorporating entries from neighboring days or extending beyond the set end date.

**Seeking Assistance:**
I'm seeking advice, suggestions, or insights from the community:

Are there potential pitfalls in date comparisons or adjustments within the Cloud Function code that might cause these discrepancies?
Any guidance or suggestions on refining the date range filtering logic to ensure accurate and precise data retrieval?
Thank you for any assistance or expertise you can offer to help resolve these date range filtering challenges effectively!

Comment: Why not directly use those Date objects without converting them to string?

Comment: It didn't work as expected

Comment: Try adding some logging statements to the code to determine what date values are being produced and being compared to?